# Mysql update query, what if value didn't change? how do I check for that?

Tags: php, mysql

When executing UPDATE statement, if value is same as new value than rowCount doesn't change. But for purposes of my application this is also a success. So how do I check for successful update no matter if value changed or not?

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE users SET name = :name WHERE id = :id');

$result = $stmt->rowCount(); // 1

if ($result == 1) {echo "success!";}
```

Comment: @user2092317: Num rows affected will return 0, if he will updating same value...

Comment: How can _this_ return a `rowCount()` of 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not executing the query, merely *preparing* it. So `rowCount()` will report an invalid number of rows (the one referring to the *last executed query*), since no rows were affected yet, and the system doesn't know beforehand how many will be, once you execute the prepared statement with specific param values.

You should check for success *upon executing* the statement. The `execute()` method will return `true` if it succeeds and `false` otherwise. So if execution success is the only thing you need, then you should do it along the lines of:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE users SET name = :name WHERE id = :id');

$result = $stmt->execute($params); // <-- execute first!

if ($result) {echo "success!";}
```

Comment: I think this answer is the best atm. All the other answers over-complicate a simple task.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with **Legionar**. But instead of count I used to add a column that contains the last update time. So that I can use that to get the entries that got updated after a specific time. In this way I able to reduce the number of entries send to client. The final decision is based on your requirement.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE users SET name = :name, updateTime = currentTime WHERE id = :id');   
$result = $stmt->rowCount(); // 1
if ($result == 1) {echo "success!";}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this cant be done normally, but you can use another column for help.

Add column `counter` to your `users` table. And then just increase this value on each update.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE users SET name = :name, counter = counter + 1 WHERE id = :id');

$result = $stmt->rowCount(); // 1

if ($result == 1) {echo "success!";}
```

So now, doesnt matter, if value `name` will change or not, `counter` will change each time, so it will return each time `1` if successed.

Or also as **Damodaran** answered, instead of `counter` you can use current datetime when doing update.

Comment: This is an unnecessary complication. What if I had to do it for _all_ tables in my DB?